# I need help to empty text area on particular conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text area controls in my page and I had code it such way that when user click on text area or hit 'ENTER' key that time it will create bullet-list in text area. But problem is that if user click on text area and it will create bullet-list but if user does not type anything in text area then it should get empty and bullet should be removed. In simple way text area bullet-list should get removed if it has no data in it. 
And one more thing is to prevent user deleting bullet from text area.

here is my code :

```
<textarea name="MondayAcomp" id="MondayAcomp" cols="45" rows="5"  onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;" onKeyUp="bulletOnEnter(this.id)" onFocus="onfoc(this.id)" onBlur="onFocOff(this.id)" style="margin: 0px; width: 200px; height: 219px;"></textarea>
```

**Javascript functions:**

```
function onfoc(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).value == "") {
        document.getElementById(id).value += '• ';
    }
}

function onFocOff(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).value == '• ') {
        document.getElementById(id).empty;
    }
}

function bulletOnEnter(id) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if (keycode == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(id).value += '\n• ';
    }

    var txtval = document.getElementById(id).value;

    if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
        document.getElementById(id).value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6449527/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is not `.empty`, it is `.value = "";`.
2. For the `keyCode` you need to pass `event` parameter to your callback function too.
3. You can prevent adding empty lines, by checking the last line in your `return` key callback too.
4. Only way I can imageine, to prevent deleting the bullets, is a loop at the end and check each line start.

```js
function onfoc(id) {
    if( document.getElementById(id).value == '' ) {
        document.getElementById(id).value +='• ';
    }
}

function onFocOff(id) {
    if( document.getElementById(id).value == '• ' ) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
    }
}

function bulletOnEnter(event, id) {
    event = event || window.event;

    // handle 'return' key
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.charCode || event.which;
    var txtval = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if( keycode == 13 && txtval.substr(txtval.length - 2) != '• ' ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(id).value += '\n• ';
    }

    // remove possible last empty line
    txtval = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if( txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n' ) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
    }

    // check if each line starts with a bullet
    var lines = document.getElementById(id).value.split('\n')
    for( var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( lines[i].substr(0, 1) !== '•' ) {
            lines[i] = '•' + lines[i];
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = lines.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="MondayAcomp" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;" onKeyUp="bulletOnEnter(event, this.id)" onFocus="onfoc(this.id)" onBlur="onFocOff(this.id)"></textarea>
```

As additional answer, I converted the code to use jQuery instead of plain JS, because you tagged your question with `jQuery`.

```js
$('#MondayAcomp').on({
    focus: function() {
        if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '• ');
        }
    },
    blur: function() {
        if( $(this).val() == '• ' ) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
        if( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
        var element = $(this),
            value = element.val();

        // handle 'return' key
        if( e.keyCode == 13 && value.substr(-2) != '• ' ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            element.val((value += '\n• '));
        }

        // remove possible last empty line
        if( value.substr(-1) == '\n' ) {
            element.val((value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1)));
        }

        // check if each line starts with a bullet
        var lines = element.val().split('\n')
        for( var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            if( lines[i].substr(0, 1) !== '•' ) {
                lines[i] = '•' + lines[i];
            }
        }
        element.val(lines.join('\n'));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="MondayAcomp"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks sir its working well. but it allows user to delete bullet, i want to prevent user doing this. plz help..

Comment: i don't understand sir what you have done, its functionality seems as it was. sill it allows user to delete bullet symbol

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you need to pass the `event` parameter to the `bulletOnEnter` function to receive the `keyCode`. Compare my `bulletOnEnter` to yours, you will see the difference. ;) But please note, on the `textarea` element you need to change it to `onKeyUp="bulletOnEnter(event, this.id)"` too. @ZalaKrunal

Comment: i did it but it still allows user to delete bullet symbol ' • '.

Comment: Thank you sir for such great help... :)